# ActionScript 3: Bullet Ricocheting

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, physics, bullet

I've been having a problem with my Actionscript code. I am fairly new to Flash and AS3, so I apologize if my code seems crude or rudimentary, but I'm doing this as best as I can.

Well, in this project I'm trying to get a bullet to ricochet off a wall once.  If it hits a wall again after ricocheting, the bullet will disappear.

I've created a for loop which moves the bullets, in an array.  At the same time, I try to keep track of each bullet's individual number of ricochets.  This works fine when I shoot a first bullet - it will ricochet and then disappear after hitting another wall.  However, every bullet I fire after that disappears on the first wall it hits, before it has ricocheted.  I've tried to get this to work but I just can't seem to do it.

I would be grateful if somebody could show me the problem, or suggest a change to my code.
[Here is a link to my code as it is now.](http://pastebin.com/R0iyXe7r)

Thanks, to anybody who helps.

Comment: accept game-development tag change to get more help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that.

Comment: I suggest creating a `Bullet` class that holds information about how many times it has hit a wall so you can work with your information more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions I have:

**1:** Create a `Bullet` class that tracks its own collisions against walls. I'd also move the `clearBullet()` method into the bullet class itself.

```
public class Bullet extends Sprite
{

    public var collisions:int = 0;
    public var xv:Number = 0;
    public var yv:Number = 0;


    public function clear():void
    {
        if(parent)
            parent.removeChild(this);
    }

}
```

**2:** Update your loop to deal with this new info.

```
for each(var i:Bullet in bulletholder)
{
    // Move bullet.
    // Check for collision.

    // When there is a collision, do this:
    i.collisions ++;

    if(i.collisions >= 2)
    {
        var n:int = bulletholder.indexOf(i);
        bulletholder.splice(n, 1);

        i.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        // Deal with changing bullet position.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least a couple of problems with your code:

1. Your `ricochetcount` is clearly out of sync. i.e. you need to delete an element from that array as well.
2. When you delete an element from the `bulletholder` array (via `clearBullet`), you're still incrementing `i`, which means you end up inadvertently skipping an element.

Also I'm not sure why you need `clearBullet()`. You already have the index `i` as well as a reference to the bullet object right there in the main loop.